# In this letter template, how to make contact details footer appear only in the last page?

Tags: moderncv, letters

This is a 2-pages cover letter. In **both** of pages my contact details appear in the footer at the bottom of page. How to make the footer (contact details) at the bottom on page appear **only** in the second page?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}      
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
\name{John}{Templeton}
\title{Resumé title}                             
\address{36 Mauniour, Valybir, Alcansa}{}{United States}
\phone[mobile]{+19193433283}                  
\email{rrewwtrni@gmail.com}    
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{r\_ratreei@epi.ac.us}}

\newlength{\currentparskip}

\begin{document}

\recipient{Department of Philology \\
Faculty of Humanities \\
University California\\
Elgsdelaan 1105 \\
1081 HV California\\
M.h.vertt@mi.us\\
Job number:5675}{}

\date{\today}


\opening{To whom it may concern,}
\closing{Yours sincerely,\vspace{-0.5cm}}
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}

The body of the letter

\vspace{0.5cm}

\enclosure [\upshape Attached]{\upshape resume, writing sample.}      

\makeletterclosing

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add

```
\thispagestyle{empty} % <===============================================
```

where you need it to suppress the footer.

See the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
\name{John}{Templeton}
\title{Resumé title}                             
\address{36 Mauniour, Valybir, Alcansa}{}{United States}
\phone[mobile]{+19193433283}                  
\email{rrewwtrni@gmail.com}    
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{r\_ratreei@epi.ac.us}}

\newlength{\currentparskip}

\begin{document}

\recipient{Department of Philology \\
Faculty of Humanities \\
University California\\
Elgsdelaan 1105 \\
1081 HV California\\
M.h.vertt@mi.us\\
Job number:5675}{}

\date{\today}


\opening{To whom it may concern,}
\closing{Yours sincerely,\vspace{-0.5cm}}
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}

The body of the letter

\thispagestyle{empty} % <===============================================

\vspace{0.5cm}

\blindtext 

\vspace{7.5cm}

\blindtext 

\vspace{5.0cm}

\blindtext

\enclosure [\upshape Attached]{\upshape resume, writing sample.}      

\makeletterclosing

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf

[image]

Comment: @user157323: The correct way to thank users for their work is to accept the solution **and** upvote the answer!